# Is Dahi Thermophilic or Mesophilic?

Tags: yogurt

Is Dahi (Indian homemade yogurt) [Thermophilic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermophile) or [Mesophilic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesophile)?

Comment: Is your actual question what temperature to incubate yogurt at? Or do you really just want to know about these broad labels?

Comment: I guess, I "want to know about these broad labels", in the  context of fermentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Traditional Foods: General and Consumer Aspects](https://books.google.com/books?id=D-K9CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=dahi%20thermophilic&source=bl&ots=PNjkHja4fl&sig=ghhbyECOfTTT1PfpdONJl_fqznc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0v46Xh-rXAhUHKyYKHbpcCwEQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=dahi%20thermophilic&f=false) page 103:

As specified under the Food Adulteration act of 1955 (India):

> Mild dahi is made from mesophillic lacto cocci such as...
>   ...Sour dahi contains additional cultures belonging to the thermophilic group.

Looks like there's a lot more info in the link, including typical prep methods.